# MacTex 2016 Compile Generates Errors

Tags: koma-script, typearea

I have recently updated Mactex to version 2016. Using TexStudio (latest version) previously, using MacTex 2015 my files compiled with no errors. Now, using Mactex 2016 a compile of five different main.tex files generates the same errors. I would be grateful if anyone has any suggestions? Thanks: Mike

```
at \begin{document} in Main.tex missing number treated as zero
at \begin{document} in Main.tex illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)
at \begin{document} in Main.text missing number treated as zero
at \begin{document} in Main.tex illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)
```

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,british,twoside,openany,headings=small]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline=.25pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scshape\small}%changed to small caps in headers
\clearpairofpagestyles% remove default header and footer content
\cehead{Ben Francis}
\cohead{\rightmark}% section in header
\ofoot{} %Author Name
\ifoot{} % Chapter Number
\ohead{\pagemark}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=5.06in,paperheight=7.81in,
    verbose,
    margin=0.75in,
    headheight=0.1in,
    headsep=0.15in,
    footskip=0.45in,
    }
\renewcommand*\raggedsection{\centering}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily} %for headings
\setkomafont{section}{\fontsize{35}{30}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\small}

\linespread{1.05}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\addchap{ONE}
\addsec{First section}
\lipsum
\addchap{TWO}
\addsec{Second section}
\lipsum
\addchap{THREE}
\addsec{Third section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what are you compiling with? I can see you are using `fontspec` which suggest `xelatex` or `lualatex`, the later has changed a LOT. So specifying the engine is very important here.

Comment: I am compiling with the default compiler - Lualatex located at: Library/TeX/texbin/lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

Comment: try adding `luatex85` to your preamble. Also there might be open issues with KOMA versus LuaLaTeX, http://www.komascript.de/release3.20

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 2016-06-26 edit

This bug in `typearea.sty` got fixed in Komascript 3.21 which was released on 2016-06-17.

Update your TeX distribution and the Problem should be gone.

### original post

It is a simple typo in `typearea.sty` (missing backslashes) which will be 
corrected with the next update. As a workaround use the option `pagesize=false` as suggested in http://www.komascript.de/release3.20

The correct code in typearea (line 477) should look like this:

```
\newcommand{\set@pdftexpagesize}{%
  \scr@ifundefinedorrelax{pdfpagewidth}{%
    \scr@ifundefinedorrelax{pagewidth}{}{\pagewidth=\paperwidth}%
  }{\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}%
  \scr@ifundefinedorrelax{pdfpageheight}{%
    \scr@ifundefinedorrelax{pageheight}{}{\pageheight=\paperheight}%
  }{\pdfpageheight=\paperheight}%
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ulrike - the workaround worked. I simply dumped 'pagesize=false' as an option in \documentclass[...] and it worked brilliantly.

Comment: Komascript 3.21 is out.